# Do Jenkins multibranch Pipelines allow remote triggers?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to to allow my multibranch Jenkins Pipeline to be triggered from a script. However each time I check the box and enter my token name and hit save, it does not save the configuration. When I next hit edit configuration the checkmark next to "Trigger builds remotely" is no longer checked.

Is this intentional? Do MultiBranch Pipeline jobs not support remote triggers?

Comment: does https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin solve your problem?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, for now, it is possible to trigger the build of a multibranch pipeline, but the token is simply ignored.

If you go in a branch of your multibranch pipeline and go to "View Configuration", you can try to check "Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)" and see that it gives you a link like `JENKINS_URL/job/<your-multibranch-pipeline>/job/<your-branch>/build`.

That sounds a bit like a hack, and you might have authentication problems depending on your setup, but otherwise it does trigger the build with Jenkins 2.30.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.  Haven't found a solution yet, but there is [a bug report open against it](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-35310).